# pattern replacement using sed

Tags: awk, sed

Can anyone please suggest how to solve this? Suppose I have a file, and I want to replace the first occurrence of a pattern in matching line with some dynamic value. The pattern here is `as`.

source file:

```
a b c as aa as
as b d f aa sa
df as kf as df
```

target file:

```
a b c 1 aa as
2 b d f aa sa
df 3 kf as df
```

Comment: a "dynamic" value, meaning "starting at 1, and incrementing by 1"?

Answer (score 3):

Since the replacement pattern changes every time, this might be more of an awk thing:

```
awk 'BEGIN { needle=1 } /as/ { $0=gensub( /as/, needle, 1, $0 ); needle=needle+1} { print } ' /path/to/input
```

The above works with `GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)`

Comment: I have revised and retested; it will now also print lines that _don't_ have a match for `/as/`.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use sed, this can be done nicely within a while loop:

```
count=1;
while read line
    do sed 's/as/'"$count"'/1' <<< "$line";
    count=$((count+1));
done < source_file >> target_file
```

The enclosing `''` pair of `"$count"` is needed for the shell to do the proper expansion of the variable for use inside the sed command.

**Even shorter (thanks to Kusalananda)**:

```
while read line
    do sed 's/as/'"$(( ++count ))"'/1' <<< "$line";
done < source_file > target_file
```

**If you only want to increment if pattern was found:**

```
count=1;
while read line;
    do sed '/as/! {q100}; s/as/'"$count"'/1' <<< "$line";
    [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]] && (( ++count ));
done < source_file > target_file
```

Comment: No need for the `;` (only useful if several statements on same line), and you could change the `>>` to just `>`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Correct, but I'll leave the semicolon, because of my personal coding style preference :) . Concerning the working of the  `>`, this means the file is just opnened once and not over and over again after every iteration step.

Comment: `>>` means "append to" while `>` means "truncate first". Putting either after the `done` will only ever open the file for writing once. Had you put the output redirection after the `sed` instead, it would have made more sense to use `>>` than `>` (`>` would have emptied the file in each iteration). However, putting `>>` after `sed` is slightly less efficient (opening the file several times) than putting `>` after `done` (opening the file once).

Comment: _The enclosing '' pair of "$count" is needed..._ : You can avoid this by enclosing the whole sed in double quotes : `sed "s/as/$(( ++count ))/1"`. Same result but more pretty :-)

Comment: @Kusalananda: Yep, this is my understanding as well.

Comment: @George Vasiliou: Thanks, you never stop learning :-).

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -pe 'BEGIN{$n=1} s/as/$n++/e' file
a b c 1 aa as
2 b d f aa sa
df 3 kf as df
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small python script that can do what you ask.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
counter = 0
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fd:
    for line in fd:
        new_words = []
        words = line.strip().split()
        found = False
        for word in words:
            val = word
            if word == 'as' and not found:
                counter += 1
                found = True
                val = str(counter)
            new_words.append(val)

        print(" ".join(new_words))
```

And a test run:

```
$ ./substitute_dynamic_val.py input.txt                                                                                  
a b c 1 aa as
2 b d f aa sa
df 3 kf as df
```